# Count instances of each combo of transitions between events?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with sequences of events: one column IDs a person, one column IDs the sequence number, and one column IDs the event.

```
existing_df <- data.frame (person  = c("john", "john", "jane","jane","jane"),
                  event = c("skate", "sit", "walk","skate","sit"),
                  sequenceNum = c(1,2,1,2,3)
                  )
```

I need to transform this to count the number of transitions between each step:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(
  source=c("skate","walk"), 
  target=c("sit","skate"), 
  value=c(2,1)
  )
```

I could do this with a loop but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with tidyr or dplyr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using `count` and `separate_wider_delim` to separate the variables. Assuming *sequenceNum* is in the right order. Add `arrange(person, sequenceNum)` if necessary.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

existing_df %>% 
  reframe(res = paste(event, lead(event)), .by = person) %>% 
  count(res, name = "value") %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(res, " " , names = c("source", "target")) %>% 
  filter(target != "NA")
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  source target value
  <chr>  <chr>  <int>
1 skate  sit        2
2 walk   skate      1
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasted a lot of time on trying to figure this out on my own. Because some of my events have spaces, e.g. "downhill ski", I modified to 

reframe(res = paste(event, lead(event), sep = "\t"), .by = person) 
AND
separate_wider_delim(res, " \t" , names = c("source", "target"))

Answer (score 0):

add an extra column (target) within your person group, filter NAs and then count

```
library(tidyverse)

existing_df |> 
  
  group_by(person) |> 
  mutate(target = lead(event)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  
  filter(!is.na(target)) |> 
  count(source = event, target)
```